# In GWT, an asynchrounous call is already in progress If we refresh the browser now, that event is firing but the process is not completing

Tags: java, gwt

In GWT, an asynchrounous call is already in progress and i will fire an event after completing this call. If we refresh the browser now, that event is firing but the process is not completing, how can i solve this. Please help.

This is the code block i am using:

```
 private void rpcMethod(final String nounToTrack, final ImportResultDTO importResult,         final String selectedNounName) {
        service.checkNounImportExportStatus(nounToTrack, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {
                if (caught instanceof StatusCodeException) {
                    eventBus.fireEvent(new CurrentNotificationChangedEvent(true));
                } else {
                    caught.printStackTrace();
                    rpcToRemoveNounImportExportStatusAttribute(nounToTrack);
                }
                clearDataGridHeaders();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final String result) {

                if (result.equals(BodDeskMessageConstants.COMPLETED) || result.contains(BodDeskMessageConstants.EXCEPTIONSTATUS)) {
                    if (result.contains(BodDeskMessageConstants.EXCEPTIONSTATUS)) {
                        eventBus.fireEvent(new CurrentNotificationChangedEvent(true));
                    } else {
                        log.info("new notification is occurring..... 3");
                        eventBus.fireEvent(new CurrentNotificationChangedEvent(true));
                    }
                }  else {
                    rpcToCheckNounImportExportStatus(nounToTrack, importResult, selectedNounName);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

if the rpc call failed/succeeded, we are firing an event to see the new notification avaialble. Now, i started this rpc call, i refreshed the browser while the rpc call is executing. The event is firing but the process is not completed. Please suggest how to restrict the firing of the event ?

Comment: I think you will get a StatusCodeException when the socket is closed. Check the status code. Maybe you can solve your problem by looking for a special status code.

Answer (score 1):

When you unload the page (which also happens when you refresh it), all ongoing requests are aborted and you get a `StatusCodeException` with a `getStatusCode()` of `0` (note: you'll get the same behavior whichever the trigger for aborting the request: network error, etc.)

You could then check the status code in your `onFailure`, but if you don't want false positives for other cases of status code 0, you'll have to listen for `WindowClosingEvent` and set a flag there. Just be sure to set the flag back at some other event (e.g. a successful response, or non-0 failure) in case the user cancels the navigation.